# Archiva REST-API

Tags: rest, maven, archiva

I'm trying to get the latest version of an artifact.
going to `http://archiva:8080/restServices` shows me the `Available RESTful services:` clicking on `http://archiva:8080/restServices/archivaServices?_wadl` leads to an empty(all white) page fore me. Opening the Development tools in my browser I get this output in the javascript-console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
GET http://archiva:8080/restServices/archivaServices?_wadl 404 (Not Found)
```

I also read [here](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/adminguide/webservices/rest.html) that there should be a `application.wadl` but for me there isn't!

I use the latest(2.2.1) Standalone version from [here](http://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi)

the request for a certain artifact looks like that

```
http://archiva:8080/restServices/archivaServices/searchService/artifact?g=eu.test&a=test&v=LATEST
```

Comment: Where do you specify the coordinates of the artifact?

Comment: added the request to my question.

Comment: did you find meanwhile a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss the contextPath in the url. For example, if you want to access the ping service. The url could be:
http://localhost:8080/archiva/restServices/archivaServices/pingService/ping.
Please notice that maybe you will get 403 due to by default archiva does not allow csrf access.
The configruation detail is: http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.3/adminguide/customising-security.html